# Error while using Admin task importSAMLIdpMetadata

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, jython, saml

I am currently trying to import identity provider metadata xml to websphere service provider using the below command in wsadmin jython

AdminTask.importSAMLIdpMetadata('-ssoId 1 -idpId 1 -idpMetadataFileName IDP-DD-Metadata-2014.xml -securityDomainName dd.test.net -signingCertAlias acs')

I am using websphere version 7

WASX7015E: Exception running command: "AdminTask.importSAMLIdpMetadata('-ssoId 1 -idpId 1 -idpMetadataFileName IDP-DD-Metadata-2014.xml -securityDomainName dd.test.net -signingCertAlias acs')"; exception information:
 com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.CommandException: com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.CommandException

I have even tried avoiding all other attributes except the required one idpMetadataFileName

Any idea what is going wrong ?

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: unless you find the log with more information you will not be able to solve it